# How to give a Dynamic url in the redirectTo field?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

**I want to redirect the previous url when i am entering wrong url (404) !! So i have to give a previous page url in that "RedirectTo" filed**

**App.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'Sk', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [ { path: 'announce', 
component: AnnounceComponent },{ path: '**', redirectTo: ?, pathMatch: 'full' }]},{ path: '**',component: AppComponent}];
```

Comment: I don't think you can, but you could redirect to a component in charge of doing another redirection

Comment: @David  Oh man !!! is there any way to redirect to previous url in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first import routes to component where you want to change redirectTo.
Then you can access routes in your component and change redirectTo value.

app.routing.ts :

```
export let routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
];
```

exampleComponent.ts :

```
// importing routes
import { routes } from '../app.routing';

// i'm changing it in ngOnInit for example.
ngOnInit() {

 routes[0].redirectTo = 'login';

}
```

**To redirect to previous page if entered url is wrong** :

1. Create a new component, say errorComponent. Whenever url is wrong, we use this component. So in your routes do as follows

```
    export let routes: Routes = [
       { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
    ];
```

2. In errorComponent we will write go back to previous page logic.

```
    import { Location } from '@angular/common';

    ngOnInit() {
      this.location.back();
    }
```

Comment: how to find & call a previous page url while i am entering wrong url ?

Comment: But i am  facing another one issue that is while i am refreshing the page also in that Error component is  activated.So that location back is triggered

Comment: error component will trigger only if your url path is not in routes.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience !! that is my mistake .Once again thank you for your concern.

Comment: it does not take effect , you should update the router config dynamically